# Cleaning object with JSON schema

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

with JSON schema I can validate object, but can I do clean it? 
For example I have schema

```
const s = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "p1": {"type": "string"}
    }
}
```

And Object `const o = {p1: 345, p_not_is_schema: '3333'}`, then I do something like `const oClean = schemaProcessor.clean(o, s)` and get object from o, which fit to schema s `{p1: '345'}`?

Comment: I think you could try out [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

Comment: maybe try jsonschema [default values](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html)

Comment: @AVAVT I don't need typification :)

Comment: [ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv)'s [`removeAdditional`](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#filtering-data) option does that.

Comment: @str thanks = ) I thought than It must be realised other way, without mutating object )

Comment: I dislike this way of doing it, although it would be the most effecient. You could make a copy of your data before passing it through the validation function with that option enabled. Still, I'd probably have to suggest you write your own function to do this! ajv provides a way to add your own key words, and do something based on them, but I'm not totally sure that's what you want either. Assuming your schemas are only one object deep, it wouldn't be much effort to write your own code to do this.

Comment: @Relequestual yap, it's all true, but 1) this is only example, of corse I can have many levels 2) I just thought that it is very common issue and someone already did it = )

Comment: Sadly for you, this is not a common use of JSON Schema. JSON Schema is mostly used to validate JSON. You could use `additionalProperties` false to prevent additional properties, but then the source of the JSON would need to amend their JSON accordingly.

Comment: You COULD use the validation feedback to remove bits of the JSON using the paths provided, and then try re-validating =]

Comment: @Relequestual hmm, It is fastest way to clean documents incoming from other service or client before put it in document store. Of corse we can use models etc, but it is too much code = )

Comment: The fastest way is to reject anything that doesn't conform to your schema!

Comment: @Relequestual and every time get Error when service decided to add new key? )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188219/discussion-between-relequestual-and-maksim-zarechnyi).